# Can the Actionable Message make an automatic request without any input from the user (e.g. to load the initial state from the server)?

Tags: outlook, office365, adaptive-cards, office365connectors

so I am diving into [Actionable Messages for Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/actionable-messages/) and it looks really promising. Now, what I need for my app is that the *very first state* of the card is determined by the response of an automatic REST request to a server. The flow would be like this:

1. User opens Email
2. Email automatically makes a REST request to the server
3. Server responds with some data
4. Email displays the data

As this may take a second or two, a loading animation could be shown during step 1-4 as the default card content.

**My question now is, is this behavior allowed / even possible using Actionable Messages?**